# Resources folder on Maven project lose its resource definition

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a very strange issue.
I'm using Maven.
through the Intellij project structure dialog i defined src/main/java/resources as resource folder and it works.
however, every once in a while this folder loses its resources definition and returning to be defined as regular folder.
it causes me lots of issues with logback.xml, since it can be found automatically during runtime only if it is located inside a resources folder.

what can cause this to happen?
is there a way to set folder definition through command line? (maybe it's an intellij issue)

[image: my project structure]

Comment: That rather looks like `src/main/java/resources`... Wrong place by accident?

Comment: Settings->Compiler and un-check "Use external build". Which version of  Intellij are you using. Also have you mentioned the resources in your pom.xml ?

Comment: yes, src/main/java/resources. is this wrong? what's the correct way?

Comment: `src/main/resources` instead `src/main/java/resources`.

Comment: ok, i changed it to src/main/resources and i'll monitor it

Answer (score 0):

maven resource structure should be like, *src/main/resources not* *src/main/java/resources*

[image: resource structure]